# Custom Android View slides onto screen by user gesture

Tags: android

I have fitted my app with a NavDrawer following the Android Material Design spec.
But initially the idea I had for my App's Navigation Drawer was different, I would like to maintain that design, but I need advice with the approach.

I have uploaded an image of what I would like to achieve.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzRBe.jpg

The user can click on button 2 and due to the nature of button 2, only that portion of the NavDrawer will slide out, or the user can slide the drawer out manually using a finger, and the drawer slides out and snaps to the edge of the screen just like the Android notification menu that u can slide from the top of your device.
Clicking on button four will slide the entire Group of buttons (due to the nature of content on button 4), button two would remain on the right if it were already there to start with.
Button 1 which would be the home button would check that all other buttons are in place (to the left) otherwise it draws them in then loads the home content into the main view.

I am not sure which way to approach this, using the Material Spec NavDrawer, or I custom design multiple linear layouts that follow the user's Xposition gestures.

Currently, I have a Material Spec NavDrawer, so the code is standard

Comment: see this : https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the default Android Drawer Actvitity that comes with Android studio 2.0 and modify it.
it will save you allot of bugs

if you still want to create a cosutm one 
you can either use what was suggested here >

http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/

or you can just choose one from this site >

https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=Drawer

it has some open library drawer helpers to help you write one.

i woul'd suggest against writing everything from scrach, it looks like allot of works and introduce allot of bugs, as to what needs to be on top of what every time, that you can fix by either using a library or taking the default one.